# generic interface implemented on an actual type

Tags: c#

Basically I have a collection of random model objects. I need to find out the difference between 2 given objects and update them. Each type of model (C# class) has their own way of finding out the difference (`IDifferer`).

```
interface ICollection<T> where T: BaseModel
{
    Task<bool> Update(T oldModel, T newModel, IDifferer<T> differer);
}

interface IDifferer<T> where T : BaseModel
{
    DifferResult<T> Differ(T oldModel, T newModel);
}
```

For an actual model class I need to have the following corresponding differer:

```
class MyModel: BaseModel
{
    ...
}

class MyModelDifferer: IDifferer<MyModel>
{
    DifferResult<MyModel> IDifferer<MyModel>.Differ(MyModel oldModel, MyModel newModel)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then I use the following to update on `MyModel`:

```
ICollection<MyModel> collection = ...;
MyModel oldModel = ...;
MyModel newModel = ...;
var success = await collection.Update(oldModel, newModel, new MyModelDifferer());
```

But the error is: `Cannot convert MyModelDifferer to IDifferer<BaseModel>`. Can anyone please advise how to fix this?

EDIT:
Here is some more classes/enums

```
abstract class BaseModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

class DifferResult<T> where T: BaseModel
{
    DifferenceType Difference { get; set; }
}

enum DifferenceType
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I don't get your error when I run your code. Can you provide a [mcve]? Did you mean `ICollection<BaseModel> collection = ...;` instead of `ICollection<MyModel> collection = ...;?`

Comment: * it works on my machine. Issue is with type inference. Use explicitly `Update<MyModel>` and you'll see which argument (or collection) does not fit.

Comment: @Antediluvian Can you share the `BaseModel` and `DifferResult` classes?

Comment: @Sweeper You are indeed correct. I used `BaseModel` in my actual code.

Comment: @fenixil Thanks for that.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I have now put in their declarations.